# Calendar invites working on some platforms not others

Tags: icalendar

When I execute the following code, I get proper response options (accept, reject) in Microsoft Exchange Server & Gmail (web). However, outlook.com / hotmail and iphone mail app either only see the ics attachment or in the case of hotmail (web app) only see message body.

I have an idea it has something to do with the escape characters \r\n but I would greatly appreciate some help here!

```
$from_name = "Me";        
$from_address = "me@gmail.com";          
$to_name = $fetchAlternate['name'];        
$to_address = "you@gmail.com";
$startTime = $resultSession['start_session'];        
$endTime = $resultSession['end_session'];        
$subject = $resultProgram['name'];        
$description = $resultSession['notes'];        
$location = $resultLocation['name'];
sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description, $location);


function sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address, $startTime, $endTime,     
$subject, $description, $location)
{

$domain = 'www.domain.ca';

//Create Email Headers
$mime_boundary = "----THIS WILL WORK!!!----".MD5(TIME());

$headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\r\n";

//Create Email Body (HTML)
$message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= "<html>\n";
$message .= "<body>\n";
$message .= '<p>Dear '.$to_name.',</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
$message .= "</body>\n";
$message .= "</html>\n";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
'TZID:Eastern Time' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20091101T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
'DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
'DTEND;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;

$mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

return ($mailsent)?(true):(false);
}
```